# Model class for e-commerce website ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model, properties

I don't understand the FK relationships between classes. I currently have User, Seller, Product, Cart, CartItems, TransactionHistory and TransactionHistoryItems. Please tell me if there is anything incorrect as I kept getting cascading delete problem while updating database.

This is `User` class

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }    
    public string? ProfilePic { get; set; }
    public string? Usertype { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }   
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinedDate { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public decimal CreditBalance { get; set; }
    public Cart Cart { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TransactionHistory> TransactionHistories { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `Seller` class:

```
public class Seller
{
    public int SellerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string? ProfilePic { get; set; }
    public string? Usertype { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoinedDate { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    public decimal CreditBalance { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `Product` class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string? ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategory { get; set; }
    public string? ProductImage { get; set; }
    public int StockQuantity { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("Seller")]
    public int SellerId { get; set; }
    public Seller Seller { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `Cart` class:

```
public class Cart
{
    public int CartId { get; set; }

    public decimal CartTotalPrice { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CartItem> CartItems { get; set; }
}
```

`Cart Item` class:

```
public class CartItem
{ 
    public int CartItemId { get; set; }

    public decimal CartSubtotal { get; set; }
    public int CartQuantity { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Cart")]
    public int CartId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public Cart Cart { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

`TransactionHistory` class:

```
public class TransactionHistory
{
    public int TransactionHistoryId { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; } // Foreign key for the User
    public User User { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TransactionHistoryItem> TransactionHistoryItems { get; set; }
}
```

`TransactionHistoryItem` class:

```
public class TransactionHistoryItem
{
    public int TransactionHistoryItemId { get; set; }

    public int ProductQuantity { get; set; }
    public string? ProductImage { get; set; }
    public int SellerId { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductSubtotal { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TransactionHistory")]
    public int TransactionHistoryId { get; set; }

    public TransactionHistory TransactionHistory { get; set; }
}
```

I just want a working model class and properties for an e-commerce API.